# Vertical CSS Positioning Divs Images

Tags: css, image, html, position

I need to position 3 objects as follows:

Div 1 is a absolute positioned container, with a fixed width, height and position. 
Image 1 should be an absolute positioned image, with a fixed align left position only.
Div 2 should be an absolute positioned div, with a fixed align left position only.

I need Image 1 and Div 2 to align to the vertical center of div 1, as these are variable text and image elements with a dynamic height.

Example:

Div 1 is 200px high fixed.
Image 1 is 52px high variable

Image 1 should be vertically positoned:

(200 / 2) + (52 / 2) = 126px

I've looked into CSS table-cell, vertical-align, margin as % and others but was unable to get this working.

Thanks.

```
.div1
{
position: absolute;
width: 100px;
height: 100px
top: 100px;
left: 100px;
}
.image1
{
position: absolute;
left: 10px;
// something here to align the image in the vertical middle of div1
}
.div2
{
position: absolute;
left: 60px;
// something here to align the image in the vertical middle of div1
}

<div class="div1"><img class="image1"><div class="div2"></div></div>
```

Updated code:

```
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        .div1 {
            background: yellow;
            display: table;
            position: absolute;
            width: 300px;
            height: 300px;
            top: 100px;
            left: 100px;
        }
        .newdiv {
            display: table-cell; 
            vertical-align: middle;
            height: 300px;
        }
        .image1 {
            left: 10px;
            position: relative;  
            width:50px;
            height: 80px;
            background: blue;
        }
        .div2 {
            position: relative;   
            background: red;
            left: 70px;
            width: 100%;
            height: 200px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<div class="div1"><div class="newdiv"><div class="image1" /></div><div class="div2">123</div></div></div>
```

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean by "fixed left align".. could you please provide some imagery or diagram of how this should look?

Comment: If you go here and recreate your problem it will be very helpful in getting an answer: http://jsfiddle.net/ ?

Comment: Thanks for asking for clarification. I have updated my question. I am referring to CSS. position: absolute; left: 20px;

Comment: Can you add an additional div?

Comment: So you want to vertically center an object that could change in height? Is this correct?

Comment: Hi Jim, yes, that is correct. Thanks.

Comment: @user1055774, does any of the answers answer your question? Would be nice if you accept any or point out why they don't solve your issue.

Comment: Hi @spliter. Yes, I'm still having a few issues getting this to work in IE (please see below) - Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, you have to add another div inside your first div:

```
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        .div1 {
            background: yellow;
            display: table;
            position: absolute;
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            top: 100px;
            left: 100px;
        }
        .newdiv {
            display: table-cell; 
            vertical-align: middle;
        }
        .image1 {
            left: 10px;
            position: relative;  
        }
        .div2 {
            position: relative;   
            background: red;
            left: 6px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<div class="div1"><div class="newdiv"><img class="image1" /><div class="div2">123</div></div></div>
```

UPDATE (I've found another way, without the new div, I didn't test it in IE.):

```
             <head>
                <style type="text/css">
                    .div1 {
                        background: yellow;
                        position: relative;
                        width: 300px;
                        height: 300px;
                        top: 100px;
                        left: 100px;
                    }
                    .image1 {
                        left: 10px;
                        position: absolute; 
                        width:50px;
                        height: 80px;
                        background: blue;
                        top:0;
                        bottom:0;
                        margin:auto;
                    }
                    .div2 {
                        position: absolute;    
                        background: red;
                        left: 70px;
                        width: 100px;
                        height: 200px;
                        top:0;
                        bottom:0;
                        margin:auto;
                    }
                </style>
            </head>

            <div class="div1">
                    <div class="image1" /></div>
                    <div class="div2">123</div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the code, but it's not quite there still. I need the two sub divs to act independently of one another, always aligning to the vertical center of the main div, regardless of their independent height. I have added my updated code above if you wish to try this out in browser. The code also needs to work in IE, but I will worry about this later. Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Please take a look at my updated code, maybe this works for you.

Comment: Hi Victor. That is working exactly as I need, thanks! Any idea how to get this working in IE or would it be best for me to do some research? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
.image1,
.div2 {
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    margin: auto;
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/spliter/66SqL/)

Comment: Hi Spliter. I'm running IE 8.0 and unfortunately the above code simply aligns the elements to the top of the container div when used as part of the full markup. Are you aware of any specific properties that need to be assigned to the container div, aside from position: relative? Many thanks!

Comment: Just noticed that the code works when in jsfiddle, but not when run in the browser as a .html on IE?

Comment: @user1055774 it should work just fine. Not sure what is the problem with running it as .html file, but I am pretty sure this works.  I use this technique all the time. Maybe there is something else in your .html that breaks the things.

Comment: Hi @spliter - it's working now (ran in browser and not locally!) I now need to get the two child divs to have an auto height, as they should shrink to the content within them (variable image height and variable text height) - is this something you can assist with? Thanks!

Comment: @user1055774 Since you have already accepted the previous answer, I assume that code does what you need.